# Can't store a struct containing a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, save

I have three structs :

```
struct Map
{
    int width, height;
    int* cases;
};
typedef struct Map Map;

struct Ship
{
    int x, y, length, firstShoot, color, hasBeenDiscovered;
};
typedef struct Ship Ship;

struct Player
{
    int activeShips;
    Map map[2];
    char lastMoves[5][128];
    Ship ships[10];
    int shipcolor[4];
    int color;
};
typedef struct Player Player;
```

I use the map structure as a 2d dynamic array. Here are my functions to manipulate the map :

```
void mallocMap(Map* map, int width, int height)
{
    map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);

    map->width = width;
    map->height = height;

    if (map->cases == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erreur d'allocation de memoire\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void freeMap(Map* map)
{
    free(map->cases);
}

int getMapValue(Map map, int x, int y)
{
    return *(map.cases + y*map.width + x);
}

void setMapValue(Map* map, int value, int x, int y)
{
    *(map->cases + y*map->width + x) = value;
}
```

Now what I'm doing is I'm creating a variable player of type Player, asks the user the width and height of the map and allocate memory for the map (`malloc(sizeof(int)*width*height)`).
Next what I want to do is to be able to store the struct Player in a file and the values of the cases but I don't know how I could do it.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to store an integer in a structure? You force yourself into using `malloc()` and there is no need. If `games` was simple a `int` then `fwrite(&player, 1, sizeof(player), file)`/fread(&player, 1, sizeof(player), file)` would be enough.

Comment: Hm, you are using a type `Map` in your struct, which doesn't seem to exist... The typedef creates a type `map`. Is that the actual code?

Comment: `printf("Error")` is always, *always*, **always** (well, almost always) wrong!!   Errors belong on stderr, not on stdout.  `if(( fp = fopen(path,mode)) == NULL) { perror(path); ... }`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I simplified my code here but I need to store more than just an int.
@Ctx it was an error, it's `typedef struct Map Map`

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to store a pointer in a file and use it at a later time?

Comment: I'm totally not expecting that, that's the reason why I store the value at the pointer adress separately when I save the file and then store it back at the new pointers adress when I load the file.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int))` is totally fishy.

Comment: You can write your structure without pointers at all. And if you must, then it's only because you have to store a string. In that case you can store the length of the string somewhere and then use it to read the string. Your "*sample*" code or "*simplified*" version does not ressemble your real intention. Developing a file format is something I find very amusing.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile and it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I will post a whole new code without simplifying it, I think it will be better for you to understand what my problem is.

Comment: player.map is a pointer to a struct Map.  player.map.cases is a syntax error.  The typedefs are causing unnecessary confusion

Comment: Not really wrong, but that typedef struct Map Map looks very ugly

    typedef struct _Map {
         int *cases;
    } Map;

Comment: Consider including in your simplification the suggestion by @IharobAlAsimi to stop using pointers in your struct where you do not need them, as well as making it a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I updated all my code so you can see what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Drakalex this is _completely_ different from your previous situation! Back to square zero...

Comment: Should I ask a new question with this code ? I'm really stuck

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading the values back in properly:

```
    fseek(file, sizeof(Player), SEEK_SET); // set the cursor after the struct
    fread(&player->games, sizeof(int), 1, file); // read the value

    fseek(file, sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR); // set the cursor after the first value
    fread(&player->map.cases, sizeof(int), 1, file); // read the value
```

In the first read, you pass in `&player->games` as the address to write to.  This expression has type `int **`.  Rather than writing into the memory you allocated, you're writing into the pointer that contains that address.  The same problem exists in the other read.

Remove the address-of operator from each of the `fread` calls.  Also, the calls to `fseek` are redundant since the file pointer is already at the correct place, so you can remove them.

```
    fread(player->games, sizeof(int), 1, file); // read the value
    fread(player->map.cases, sizeof(int), 1, file); // read the value
```

Comment: Thanks, and also I had to replace the printf("%d", player.games); with printf("%d", *player.games); and the two values shows correctly.